# What are the basic ratios for making a chutney

Tags: apples, chutney

I'm looking to make a apple chutney from 6.5 kg of apples. I can't really find a recipe that I'm happy with, so I'm going to just wing it.

What are the basic ratios for a generic chutney? For example, the ratio of fruit to vinegar to sugar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The average of four different recipes that use apples or pears to make a chutney suggest the ratios

> 1.3lb of fruit : 1 cups of sugar : 0.9 cup of vinegar

or in units related to the metric system

> 300g of fruit : 100g of sugar : 100ml of vinegar

The fruit weight is for peeled and cored apples or pears, the 0.9 cups is the same as filling a cup and then taking out 2 tablespoons.

If you add cayenne to the recipe you may want to increase the sugar a bit. If you add raisins, decrease the sugar.

If you end up with 6kg of diced apples, then use 2kg of sugar and 2l of vinegar.